# How do I ensure a Class can call a method on another Class, but not other Classes can call that method?

Tags: c#

I have two classes that I'd like to keep in separate files.

```
namespace GridSystem
{
    public class Grid
    {
        public void AddItem(GridItem item)
        {
            item.InformAddedToGrid();
        }
    }
}

namespace GridSystem
{
    public class GridItem
    {
        public void InformAddedToGrid()
        {
            Debug.Log("I've been added to the grid");
        }
    }
}
```

How do I ensure no other classes are allowed to call InformAddedToGrid?

I'm trying to emulate Actionscript namespaces, which can be used on a method, in place of public, private, internal, etc. It doesn't exactly protect the method, but forces an extra step of including the namespace before the method can be accessed. Is there an alternative approach to this in C#?

Comment: Change it to `private` method.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for the C# equivalent of C++ `friend`. I don't think that exists.

Comment: When it's private Grid can't access it neither.

Comment: @Mysticial It doesn't exist. Closest thing is `internal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that you should do this,  you should do what TGH suggests,  have a public interface for GridItem, and have gridItem nested in Grid (then have a factory method on Grid to create Items and use partial Grid class to have them in separate files).

Because there isn't a way of having friend methods ( you can do friend classes through `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` )

You *COULD* do this ( but don't... )

```
public partial class Grid
{
   public void AddItem(GridItem item)
   {
      item.InformAddedToGrid();
   }
}        

public class GridItem
{
   public void InformAddedToGrid()
   {                
      if (new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType != 
                   typeof(Grid)) throw new Exception("Tantrum!");
      Console.WriteLine("Grid called in...");

   }
}
```

then

```
 var g = new Grid();
 g.AddItem(new GridItem()); // works
 new GridItem().InformAddedToGrid(); // throws a tantrum...
```

Comment: Out of curiosity are you saying don't normally use `partial` or were you just referring to the entire example when you said `but don't...`?

Comment: Method inlining can kill you with walking the stack like that. And the performance of such a method is going to be terrible.

Comment: So you're referring to `if (new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType != 
                   typeof(Grid)) throw new Exception("Tantrum!");` as being a bad idea?

Comment: @jmstoker yes, I'm talking about finding out the calling type, bad idea, but just putting it out there just in case its useful to someone someday that happens to stumble acrosss this

Comment: I actually like this answer because I can wrap that StackTrace check in a conditional compiler directive. I only want to alert my fellow developers if they're using the classes improperly, assuming they haven't RTFM. In a release product, I won't need to perform this check. This also keeps the classes nice and separate. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, I would also NOT recommend this to most people who come across this solution while searching. But it works for me!

Answer (score 5):

If GridItem itself can be hidden from the outside world as well I would consider putting GridItem inside Grid as a nested class. That way it won't be visible outside of the class

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20628/A-Tutorial-on-Nested-Classes-in-C

Comment: according to his API on grid, he has the concept of exposing GridItem to the external world,  which makes sense

Comment: Ok I would put an interface on GridItem without the method defined and then expose that to the outside world. That way you can expose what you need to expose from the original GridItem class to the outside world but still hide the method in question

Answer (score 1):

A really ugly answer would be to make it private and use reflection.

Another ugly answer would be to make it throw an exception if the caller is wrong.

Both of these are much slower to execute than a normal call also.

I don't think there's a good answer.  C# doesn't have friends.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the answer is simple: access modifiers are just there to remind the programmer of the *intent* of how public/private a class should be. Through reflection you can lift those barriers.

The usage you make of a class is all in your hands: if your class is *meant* to only be used in one place, make it so. If anything, if a class has a special way of being used, document it - put it in the XML comments.

That said, in this specific example I'd believe since the `GridItem` doesn't add itself to the grid, it's not its job to notify about it (what if "*I've not been added to the grid*"?). I think `InformAddedToGrid` belongs somewhere in your `Grid` class as a `private` method, where there's a concept of *adding an item*... assuming that's what `AddItem(GridItem)` really does.

Comment: Even if InformAddedToGrid is a member of Grid, GridItem will still have public accessors that I want reserved for classes in the GridSystem namespace. For example, InformAddedToGrid might modify GridItem's X and Y values. I ONLY want GridSystem classes to be able to write X and Y values, and classes outside of GridSystem to only read X and Y values.

Comment: Documentation can only go so far IMHO. I'm usually Pythonic with regard to access, but I would like to be more fool-proof in this particular case (which is why I asked the question).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as TGH suggested, with nested classes, except the other way around. Nest `Grid` within `GridItem` and make `InformAddedToGrid` private. Here I use a nested base class so the public API can remain the same. Note that no one outside of your assembly can inherit from `GridBase` because the constructor is internal.

```
public class GridItem
{
    public class GridBase
    {
        internal GridBase() { }

        public void AddItem(GridItem item)
        {
            item.InformAddedToGrid();
        }
    }

    private void InformAddedToGrid()
    {
        Debug.Log("I've been added to the grid");
    }
}

public class Grid : GridItem.GridBase { }
```

Another option is to have `GridItem` explicitly implement an internal interface. This way no one outside of your assembly can use the interface by name and therefore cannot call `InformAddedToGrid`.

```
public class Grid
{
    public void AddItem(GridItem item)
    {
        ((IGridInformer)item).InformAddedToGrid();
    }
}

public class GridItem : IGridInformer
{
    void IGridInformer.InformAddedToGrid()
    {
        Debug.Log("I've been added to the grid");
    }
}

internal interface IGridInformer
{
    void InformAddedToGrid();
}
```